# Robot model config for cartographer

Tags: ros, cartographer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to make a map using cartographer and I do not know how to make the robot model.
Is there a tutorial for the robot model or can i make a map without a robot model?
I am using the backpack_2d that came with the cartographer and i modified it to not include odometry and changed num_laser_scans = 1,
num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0
in the lua file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278162/robot-model-config-for-cartographer/) by [Jnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33021/jnus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can load a map in ROS without having a robot model, check out the map server: http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

To model robots, you need to learn XML and more specifically URDF (Universal Robot Description Format), best place to start is here: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf

After you learn URDF check Xacro too, it's like URDF with some extra macros.

It seems you are trying to do SLAM since you are using cartographer, I'd recommend you learn more about the ROS environment before.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0